# Select previous and next row with condition in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, select

```
ID   BegCha EnCha   Val
10      20  30      250
10      30  40      140
10      50  60      189
20      10  20      250
20      20  30      157
20      30  40      199
20      40  50      70
```

Find all the rows where value is above 249

```
select * from table where Val >249
```

```
select One row previous and one row after if the values are 50 of 250
```

```
select * from table where id in (select * from table where Val >249) and Val > 149
```

What I am expecting to get is as under:

```
ID   BegCha EnCha   Val
10      20  30      250
10      30  40      140
10      50  60      189
20      10  20      250
20      20  30      157
```

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY`, the next and previous rows can be different from each time - you are never guaranteed the same order unless an `ORDER BY` is provided. So, how do you want to sort the dataset?

Comment: Is there any more information to talk about your logic? I can't get your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this table

```
create table prueba(
    id int ,
    BegCha int,
    EndCha int,
    Val int);
```

this data

```
id  BegCha  EndCha  Val
10  20      30      250
10  30      40      140
10  50      60      189
20  10      20      250
20  20      30      157
20  30      40      199
20  40      50      70
```

and this Query

```
WITH pruebaNumerada AS  
(  
    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) AS RowNumber,
      id, BegCha, EndCha, val
    FROM prueba 
) 
SELECT b.id, b.BegCha, b.EndCha, b.val
FROM pruebaNumerada a  
inner  join pruebaNumerada b on b.RowNumber  between a.RowNumber-1 and a.RowNumber+1
WHERE a.val >=250;
```

I obtain this result

```
id  BegCha  EndCha  val
10  20      30      250
10  30      40      140
10  50      60      189
20  10      20      250
20  20      30      157
```

Answer (score 0):

Are looking for something like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id 
    FROM table 
    WHERE Val >249
) 
AND Val > 149
```